# Does Bitcoin Core still use "Bitcoin seed" in addition to a seed like stated in BIP 32?

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key, bip32-hd-wallets

In BIP 32 it's stated that a Master Private key is generated by hashing the concatenation of a random seed and the string "Bitcoin seed". And is like so in the example implementations.

But I couldn't find such string on Bitcoin Core's codebase. Is the seed just hashed directly to form the Master Key and Master chain code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, I found the bit of code that uses "Bitcoin seed". So yes, Bitcoin Core uses the string "Bitcoin seed" in tandem with a random seed.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/d0f81a96d9c158a9226dc946bdd61d48c4d42959/src/key.cpp#L302